# Usage of state and props

Tags: reactjs

I want to sort my table with `insuranceList` . It is passed from the component like this

```
<DashboardAddInsuranceStep2
  insuranceList={insuranceSearchList}
/>
```

DashboardAddInsuranceStep2.js

```
        this.state:{
insuranceList: props.insuranceList
}
sort(event) {
        const {order} =this.state;
        let {insuranceList} = this.props;
        order[event.target.id]=! order[event.target.id];
        insuranceList= _.orderBy(insuranceList, (o)=> typeof o[event.target.id] === 'string' ? o[event.target.id].trim().toLowerCase() : o[event.target.id], order[event.target.id] ? 'asc' : 'desc');
        this.setState({
            orderby: event.target.id,
            insuranceList: insuranceList,
            order
        });
    }

render(){
const { insuranceList} = this.props;

const {order,insuranceList}= this.state;

<tr>
 <th id='Adjuster' onClick={this.sort}>Adjuster{order.Adjuster?<i className="fa fa-sort-asc"/> : <i className="fa fa-sort-desc"/>}</th>
</tr>
}
```

Since `insuranceList` is coming from component I declared it in props.
When sorting is needed I declared it in state.
While doing this error occurs.
How to avoid this?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting

Comment: @Sumanth Madishetty Error: Duplicate declaration "insuranceList"

Comment: @Davin Tryon There is no error in that part .It's for sorting

Comment: Its obvious, you are declaring two constants with the same name

Comment: @ Sumanth Madishetty  Then how can I declare it in only state(for sorting purppose), Since insuranceList is passed from a component(DashboardAddInsuranceStep2) , I declared it in props? Can I declare it in state only?

Comment: Why are you declaring another function inside the render method??

Answer (score 0):

You are destructuring state and props and giving the same name to both, Instead you can use as `this.state.insuranceList` and `this.props.insuranceList`

or you can change the name of the constant while destructuring like

```
const { insuranceList: propsInsuranceList } = this.props;
const { insuranceList } = this.state;
```

and when you use them use `propsInsuranceList` when you want to refer from props

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
const { insuranceList} = this.props;

const {order,insuranceList}= this.state;
```

You have declared two variables with the same name (`insuranceList`). They have to be unique.

You could give them different names, or just use them directly as `this.props.insuranceList` and `this.state.insuranceList` in your render:

Comment: I used props to load insuranceList (passed from a component) when Serach button is clicked. The same insuranceList need to be sorted. That's why I declared in state.